# First time welding - how to connect this steel sheet and tube better?

Tags: welding

After researching for a few weeks, making sure I understand the safety, I bought a small MIG welder/Flux Core Arc Welder:

http://www.princessauto.com/en/detail/mig-100e-flux-cored-wire-feed-welder/A-p8538886e

Here is my attempt at mounting a tube onto a sheet, both steel at 1/8" thickness:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AFqn.jpg
[image]

My technique was basically to come down at a 45deg angle and slowly move across the sides, for about 60 - 90 seconds total. I kept the tip of the gun very close to the metals, kinda just dragged it along. I chose the wire feed speed as recommended for the metal thickness according to the manual.

It felt strong but then to test it I tried stepping on it sideways. After I applied enough force (less than my bodyweight though) the tube broke off =(

What techniques should I use to weld this connection better?

Any useful vids would be great as well. Thanks!

Comment: It's a bit tough to teach somebody to weld in a short answer.  You should try watching some YouTube videos, and/reading some books on welding.  You'll also want to read the user manual for the welder, and become familiar with its operation.  Then practice, practice, practice.

Comment: From my limited experience, it looks like you didn't clean the parts well, the current is too low, you're not close enough to the joint, and you need to work on your technique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're just piddling globs of molten welding rod on top of the steel.  That's not welding, that's metal deposition.  You need to read more on how to weld and get more practice, because the concept hasn't really (forgive the pun) penetrated.

Also, it helps to grind or media blast the mill scale and other contaminants off the area you're welding.

Comment: After a better hand at welding that comes with practice, beveling the edge of the tube a bit will allow a deeper penetration of the weld

Comment: @Jack beveling the tube is the least of the problem here. Seems like there's no penetration at all in that weld.

Comment: Yes indeed, that's why the mention "after a better hand at welding". It truly is an acquired talent.